# Backslashes Removed From Anchor Stored In Meta Value

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, anchor

I've run into a slight issue when pulling links from meta values to display within a loop I have created. The trailing slashes are removed and the link is broken.

For example here's the proper link
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00IGXYARC/ref=as_li_tl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IGXYARC)?

And here's what is pulled for my anchor
http:www.amazon.comgpproductb00igxyarcref="as_li_tl?

EDIT: Here's the code pulling the link

```
 <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'amazon_affiliate_link', true ); ?>
```

Any idea how I would go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Updated - Do I need to specify characters for my get?

Comment: did you checked in mysql db, what is stored there

Comment: It's stored correctly in MYSQL, including backslashes

Comment: try testing with `print_r(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'amazon_affiliate_link', false));` what it gives

Comment: Brilliant.. that works perfectly.. any idea why?

Comment: WordPress uses some sanitize filters before output, but i think its a bug, glad it fixed